# Spring add CSS to different pages

Tags: html, spring, jsp

I have 2 pages:

- http://local.host:8080/test/login
- http://local.host:8080/test/admin/manage

Added css in login.jsp using c:url:

```
<c:url value="css/style.css"/>
```

When I open 1st link - everything works well. I tried to add the same style.css file to manage.jsp (2nd URL), but when I open 2nd link - css  is not included. In Page Source I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

How to define to take style.css from the root of URL (http://local.host:8080/test) ?

Comment: clear the cache and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is, because the specified path is relative to the current page (`login` is at an other level of path-nesting* than `admin/manage`).

*A trivial but bad solution would be adding `../` for the css of `admin/manage`. But this soultion has the drawback, that you always need to adjust the `../` when you change the level of path-nesting* for an page.*

To overcome this problem, make the path in the `c:url`-tag start with an `/`! (this make the tag aware that the url is context relative (relative to `http://local.host:8080/test/), and the tag will automatically add`http://local.host:8080/test` in front.

```
<c:url value="/css/style.css"/>
```

*will be rendered to : `http://local.host:8080/test/css/style.css`*

For the link use this way

```
<c:url value="/css/style.css" var="cssUrl"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cssUrl}"/>
```

**I do not know the correct term for "path nesting" at the moment - fell free to change it*

Answer (score 0):

Order of attribute might be the problem. Correct the order

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```